# Feeding a Smart contract with large Data

Tags: web3js, blockchain, etherscan, ethereumjs, binance-smart-chain

I want to feed a smart contract with multiple 5000 or more wallet addresses (for whitelisting purposes) in an array in a single transaction.
How can I achieve that without sending data in chunks? Sending this much data in one go is causing transaction failures, and sending it in chunks, like around 250 in a transaction, will take a lot of time and result in multiple transactions, which will be hectic.
Is there a different model or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sending such a large amount of data in a single transaction can indeed be problematic due to gas limits and other constraints imposed by the blockchain network. Breaking it down into smaller transactions is generally the recommended approach, but I understand your concerns about the overhead and time it would take.

One alternative approach you might consider is using a [**Merkle tree**](https://medium.com/coinmonks/merkle-tree-a-simple-explanation-and-implementation-48903442bc08) or a similar data structure to efficiently represent your large dataset in a compact manner. With a Merkle tree, you can generate a root hash that represents the entire dataset, and then you only need to include this single hash in your smart contract.

Here's a simplified overview of how you might implement this:

**Off-chain steps:**

1. **Generate a Merkle tree:** Take all the wallet addresses you want to whitelist and construct a Merkle tree from them. There are libraries and tools (like [this](https://github.com/merkletreejs/merkletreejs)) available to help you generate Merkle trees efficiently.
2. **Calculate the root hash:** Once you have the Merkle tree constructed, calculate the root hash of the tree. This root hash uniquely represents the entire dataset.

**On-chain steps:**

3. **Store the root hash in the smart contract:** Instead of storing all the wallet addresses directly in the smart contract, you only need to store the root hash of the Merkle tree.
4. **Verification:** When someone wants to check if their wallet address is whitelisted, they provide their address along with a Merkle proof. The smart contract can then verify the Merkle proof against the root hash stored in the contract to confirm whether the address is whitelisted or not.

This approach has several advantages:

- **Efficiency:** The Merkle tree allows you to represent a large dataset with a single hash, reducing the amount of data that needs to be stored on the blockchain and transmitted in transactions.
- **Scalability:** Because you're only dealing with a single hash, you can easily manage large datasets without running into gas limits or other constraints.
- **Security:** The Merkle proof provides cryptographic assurance that a particular wallet address is indeed part of the dataset represented by the root hash.

While implementing a Merkle tree does add complexity to your system, it can offer significant benefits in terms of efficiency and scalability, especially when dealing with large datasets on the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I'm aware about this but is there any other way than merkle tree ?

Comment: @BhushanDhiware, the other way that I can think of is the usage of IPFS CID by storing the wallet addresses as JSON on IPFS (you can also opt for some cloud storage bucket and get JSON file url instead of IPFS CID to avoid latency). So, when you call the `whitelistAddressesinBulk` function, then you can pass the JSON file url (publicly viewable) and store it in some state variable. And, for verifying the whitelisting status of a particular address, you can pass that address off-chain by utilising a blockchain oracle like Chainlink, verify it off-chain, and return the result on-chain.

Comment: I didn't get that , How can  Solidity read data from the IPFS url ?  we can store URL but how to read data from it. it will be great if you help me to understand this.

Comment: @BhushanDhiware, the URL will be passed from on-chain (smart contract) to off-chain ([external adapter](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/external-adapters/external-adapters)), using blockchain oracle like [Chainlink](https://chain.link/education/blockchain-oracles). You can see the similar thing that I've done in this [contract-kit](https://github.com/shambadynamic/shamba-smartcontractkit). Let me know if you need any further assistance when you proceed with this.